# Verify an AES-256-GCM implementation with another tool

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, aes, aes-gcm

I need to verify the correctness of a tool, that follows the FIPS-197 standard. So I will receive a triple and I want to decode this triple (key, cypher, IV).

Is there a way to do this simply? Is there any online-implementation, that could be useful?

I just found out, that not even two different pages, that have AES-256 implemented, have the same values as output.

Thank you for your help.

Edit:
I need to verify my own implementation of this, and I want to do this, by check with test-vectors, that have been verified by an already verified tool.

Edit2:
I'm looking for a way to verify my implementation. So I thought about test-vectors or another, already validated, tool. This is the part on which I need help: Where can I find test-vectors or such a tool?

## Edit3: Evaluation with php

We're using "openssl_encrypt" for evaluation.

```
$CM = "aes-256-gcm"; //cypher mode
$PT = "";//plain
$CT = "";//cypher
$key = "";
$iv = "";

$cypher = openssl_encrypt($PT, $CM, $key, $options=0, $iv, $tag);
```

If we want to evaluate the tag, we need to do:

```
print(unpack("h*", $tag)[1]);
```

Now we can see, if both are equal, regarding to "gcmEncryptExtIV256.rsp" with

> [Keylen = 256] [IVlen = 96] [PTlen = 0] [AADlen = 0] [Taglen = 128]
>
> Count = 0
>
> Key = b52c505a37d78eda5dd34f20c22540ea1b58963cf8e5bf8ffa85f9f2492505b4
>
> IV = 516c33929df5a3284ff463d7
>
> PT =  AAD =  CT =
>
> Tag = bdc1ac884d332457a1d2664f168c76f0

We have:

```
$CM = "aes-256-gcm"; 
$PT = ""; //plain
$CT = ""; //cypher
$key = "b52c505a37d78eda5dd34f20c22540ea1b58963cf8e5bf8ffa85f9f2492505b4 ";
$iv = "516c33929df5a3284ff463d7 ";

$cypher = openssl_encrypt($PT, $CM, $key, $options=0, $iv, $tag);
print(unpack("h*", $tag)[1]);
```

This is inequal to bdc1ac884d332457a1d2664f168c76f0.

So what did I do wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this is programming related?

Comment: To validate an implementation, there has to be done a test. To ensure the processed data are right, I have to take an already evaluated tool for checking on one or two test-vectors. Currently I guess, that I have to use PHP + OpenSSL.

Comment: AES is a standard, but the mode of operation, configuration parameters and encoding may still differ.

Comment: That's right. But lets say, I have used the FIPS-197 (AES-256) and NIST D800-38D (GCM) recommendations. For testing purposes, I just found this document: https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/documents/mac/gcmvs.pdf

but this does not specify any plain/cipher for testing-purpose. Its just for the gcm part. All in all I'm looking for some test-vectors or a reference implementation with verification.

Comment: @Shalec Your "Edit 3" is now fundamentally a different question, and you should roll it back and ask it as a new question instead of an edit to this one

Comment: You're right, but I'm not allowed to ask more question.

Comment: Well, I asked for evaluate with another tool, I chose PHP and openssl for that. But I cannot verify any given example vectors by this implementation. So openssl aes-256-gcm is differently implemented (differents in gcm-mode) or I do anything wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/CAVP-TESTING-BLOCK-CIPHER-MODES#GCMVS is the NIST Cryptographic Algorithm Validation Program (CAVP) page for block cipher modes, including GCM.

At the bottom it contains a link to a corpus of test vectors, https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/documents/mac/gcmtestvectors.zip

In, for example `gcmEncryptExtIV128.rsp` you get cases like

```
Count = 0
Key = 11754cd72aec309bf52f7687212e8957
IV = 3c819d9a9bed087615030b65
PT = 
AAD = 
CT = 
Tag = 250327c674aaf477aef2675748cf6971
```

So with the key `11754cd72aec309bf52f7687212e8957` (which is specified in hex) and the IV/nonce of `3c819d9a9bed087615030b65` (still hex) the empty plaintext and empty associated data should produce an empty ciphertext and an auth tag of `250327c674aaf477aef2675748cf6971` (yep, still hex).

There are a whole lot of tests of that mode (different keys, no plaintext, no AAD), then plenty of "now with AAD", then "just with plaintext", and, eventually cases like

```
Count = 14
Key = f42c74bcf473f6e923119946a89a0079
IV = 14852791065b66ccfa0b2d80
PT = 819abf03a7a6b72892a5ac85604035c2
AAD = 297007ac9419553a292b0fee3a7ac3c9
CT = 48371bd7af4235c4f11c458f1789192a
Tag = 4f44e0aff49a5a20ab2c69c834
```

Which let you check the whole kit and kaboodle.  The "one part at a time" tests failing are probably easier to debug, though.

Comment: Hey, if I try to evaluate with php, I've never reach the right answere. I will edit some php code for evaluation. It would be great, if you could help in advance.