# PHP Encrypt Decrypt

Tags: php, openssl

I have this PHP Code for encryption and decryption. This is using OpenSSL

```
<?php
//$key should have been previously generated in a cryptographically safe way, like 
openssl_random_pseudo_bytes
$plaintext = "message to be encrypted";
$cipher = "aes-128-gcm";
if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods()))
{
   $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
   $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
  $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv, $tag);
  //store $cipher, $iv, and $tag for decryption later
  $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv, $tag);
  echo $original_plaintext."\n";
}
?>
```

When you run this on your browser and refresh the page the encryption changes. So I want to know how do I use a check like if statement to see if the user input plain text matches the encrypted text.

Comment: It changes because you generate a new IV every time you execute the code. Store the IV and key and then use them for each request

Comment: What should be the purpose of "checking that the plaintext matches the encrypted text"? One of the most important things in symmetric key cryptography is randomness and so a plaintext should **never** match a ciphertext. The only "check" is done by decrypting the ciphertext using the key and (stored) iv + tag - compare this decrypted text with the original plaintext and you are fine.

Comment: If you want to check whether the _correct_ ciphertext and tag result for a _given_ plaintext, key, nonce, and possibly AAD, usually [_test vectors_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49305165/9014097) are applied. Alternatively, a comparison with a _reliable_ reference implementation is also possible.